# npm build not failing properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, npm

My package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint src tools test",
    "test": "npm run lint && mocha --compilers js:babel/register",
    "clean": "babel-node --eval \"require('./tools/clean')().catch(err => console.error(err.stack))\"",
    "build": "babel-node --eval \"require('./tools/build')().catch(err => console.error(err.stack))\"",
    "start": "babel-node --eval \"require('./tools/start')().catch(err => console.error(err.stack))\"",
    "deploy": "babel-node --eval \"require('./tools/deploy')().catch(err => console.error(err.stack))\""
}
```

When I do

```
npm run build
```

having syntax error in any file of the application. I can see the console error output in console but the build itself returns exit code 0. How can I fail the whole build?

(throw - not working)

Comment: Try to not catch the error

Comment: still the same (without error message).